# Get folder names from URL using ColdFusion

Tags: url, coldfusion, cgi

I'm trying to get part of the current URL of a page and I'm not sure how to do it. For example: A current page URL would be http://www.myurl.com/us/en/. What I need to get from the url is /us/en/. Or "http://www.myurl.com/us/en/" would also work.
Any help with this would greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is contained within the `CGI` variable scope of the ColdFusion server. You can see all of the available information form that scope if you "dump" it out.

```
<cfdump var="#cgi#">
```

*or in script syntax*

```
<cfscript>
    writedump(cgi);
</cfscript>
```

Just place that in your CFML file and look at the output.

I think what you want is contained in the `cgi.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH` and `cgi.PATH_TRANSLATED` fields.

Documentation reference - [CGI environment (CGI Scope) variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7785.html)

I created a quick code snippet that does what you want.  [Check it out here](http://trycf.com/gist/4276372ccf1dfa851c75c65f42e3be64/acf2016?theme=monokai).

```
<cfscript>
    info=replace(cgi.path_translated,cgi.script_name,'/');
    writeOutput(info);
    writeDump(cgi);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the folder actually exists. If you're using url rewriting...

```
<!--- IIS7 --->
<cfif CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL neq ''>
    <cfset urlStrings = listToArray(spanExcluding(CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL,"?"), "/")>
</cfif>
<!--- ISAPI_rewrite --->
<cfif CGI.HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL neq ''>
    <cfset urlStrings = listToArray(spanExcluding(CGI.HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL ,"?"), "/")>
</cfif>
```

After which, you can use the the url as an array.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(urlStrings)#" index="u">

<!--- THE QUERY --->
<cfquery name="test" dbtype="query" maxrows="1">
SELECT id, title, menuTitle, h1
FROM application.allNav
WHERE
    urlname = '#urlStrings[u]#' AND
    active = 1
</cfquery>
...
```

However to just get the folder names (assuming IIS):

```
<cfoutput>#spanExcluding(CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL,"?")#</cfoutput>
```